# uber api, when i get trips, get internal_server_error

Tags: uber-api

I test this request every day from different account.

```
curl -X "GET" "https://api.uber.com/v1/partners/trips" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN>"
```

All requests get error 500

```
{
    "message": "We have experienced a problem.",
    "code": "internal_server_error"
}
```

But I don't change anything and sometimes i get my trips.

How to fix this error? And stable getting my trips.

Please let me know.

Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

code 500 is server error not wrong request, if sometimes it's working that you have information is only server problem not with your code

Comment: I think so too. I hope that the support of uber will see this issue and solve the problem or will tell what the problem is.